# Animation Interpolation Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, interpolation

I would like to make an animation of an interpolation.
This is my code for the moment :

```
import scipy.interpolate as itp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update(i,Z):
    x = np.arange(0,Z.shape[0])
    y = np.arange(0,Z.shape[0])
    I = itp.interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='cubic') 
    xi = np.linspace(0, Z.shape[0]-1, Z.shape[0]+1) 
    yi = np.linspace(0, Z.shape[0]-1, Z.shape[0]+1)
    Z = I(xi, yi)
    return Z

Z = np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
matrice = ax.matshow(Z)
plt.colorbar(matrice)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=19, interval=500,fargs=(Z,))

fig.show()
```

So as you can see, I want to show the progress of the interpolation, but it doesn't work. Z matrix never changes.
Can you help me please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need `matrice.set_data(Z)` and `return matrice,` (including the comma) in the update function.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. In fact Z in parameters is always the same.

Comment: The `i` variable wasn't used in function `update`. It should be in `xi` and `yi`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Exactly - the interpolation is done in one step. There is nothing to annimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you help. I managed to to solve my problem :

```
import scipy.interpolate as itp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update(i,Z,size_initial):
    x = np.arange(0,size_initial)
    y = np.arange(0,size_initial)
    I = itp.interp2d(x, y, Z, kind='cubic') 
    xi = np.linspace(0, size_initial-1, i+size_initial) 
    yi = np.linspace(0, size_initial-1, i+size_initial)
    Z = I(xi, yi)
    matrice.set_data(Z)
    return matrice,

size_initial = 4
Z = np.random.randint(100, size=(size_initial, size_initial))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
matrice = ax.matshow(Z)
plt.colorbar(matrice)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=50, interval=500,fargs=[Z,size_initial])

fig.show()
```